# Is there a single word that means "each of which"?

Tags: single-word-requests, relative-pronouns

I usually use `each of which` like as follows:

> One big problem is decomposed into a number of subproblems, each of which implies that blah blah blah.

---

One day, I came across a word in a book that perfectly matched `each of which`. I memorized the word at that time, but now I forgot :-(

If anyone knows this word, please let me know.
I'm not sure but I remember that it was a single word that composed of relative pronoun and preposition, like `whichamongof`.

Comment: One big problem … subproblems, ***each*** implying that …

Comment: _Each of which implies_ is just a longer way of saying _which each imply._

Comment: ".... subproblems that imply"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some very slight changes: **each**

> One big problem is decomposed into a number of subproblems, each  implying...

Or

> One big problem is decomposed into a number of subproblems; each  implies...

Comment: Oh, just `each` is possible??? Wow.. You are my god.

Answer (score 1):

There is the relative pronoun ***whereof*** (archaic) but it does not include *each* in its meaning. *Whereof* means:

> of which or what:
>
> - He sees hostility, the cause ***whereof*** he does not know. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whereof))

Your sentence could be re-written as:

> One big problem is decomposed into a number of subproblems, *whereof* each implies that ...

There is also ***[whereamong](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whereamong)***, but it is even more [uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whereof%2C%20whereamong&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhereof%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhereamong%3B%2Cc0) than *whereof*.

Comment: Thanks for giving me new words :-)